# DrawerNavigator in React native not working

Tags: react-native

I am try to implement the drawernavigator in react native ...But i fail to do this i use this link for implement
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/drawer
But i am not do with this link 
The Code I use is

```
    class MyHomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawer: () => ({
      label: 'Home',
      icon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Image
          source={require('./chats-icon.png')}
          style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
        />
      ),
    }),
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
        title="Go to notifications"
      />
    );
  }
}

class MyNotificationsScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawer: () => ({
      label: 'Notifications',
      icon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Image
          source={require('./notif-icon.png')}
          style={[styles.tabIcon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
        />
      ),
    }),
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
        title="Go back home"
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
  },
});

const MyApp = DrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: MyHomeScreen,
  },
  Notifications: {
    screen: MyNotificationsScreen,
  },
});


AppRegistry.registerComponent('SimpleApp', () => SimpleApp);
```

This all data i kept in App.js file...and in index.android.js file i import this like

```
import './App';
```

This code not working it show this error.
This is the error screen shot [Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUXi9.png)

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: Sir i want a drawerNavigator which run both ios and android i follow many link for this but no one work

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/drawer

Comment: This link also use but not working

Comment: Sir if u have any drawernavigator code which run both android and ios then send me plz....

Answer (score 0):

replace your index.android.js file code with below. i have shown working example below.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  Image
} from 'react-native';
import { DrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";

class MyHomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawer: () => ({
      label: 'Home',
      icon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Image
          source={require('./chats-icon.png')}
          style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
        />
      ),
    }),
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
        title="Go to notifications"
      />
    );
  }
}

class MyNotificationsScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawer: () => ({
      label: 'Notifications',
      icon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Image
          source={require('./notif-icon.png')}
          style={[styles.tabIcon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
        />
      ),
    }),
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
        title="Go back home"
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
  },
});

const MyApp = DrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: MyHomeScreen,
  },
  Notifications: {
    screen: MyNotificationsScreen,
  },
});


AppRegistry.registerComponent('SimpleApp', () => MyApp);
```

Comment: once you run react-native run-android command, you must run react-native start command in your project folder and reload the app.

Comment: sir i do this many time but there is same error as i mention above

Comment: try these two command in your project    rm -rf node_modules &&  npm install

Comment: sir if you have an other code for drawernavigator then plz send me this code not working

Comment: This is not about code. this is all about your configuration. run this command and once again from starting     adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

Answer (score 0):

I think so there no any method to apply drawer navigator without using api i try this but not complete so i use api ,...you also use the drawer navigator api for this

Answer (score 0):

https://snack.expo.io/SJTS5z24Z

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Button,
} from 'react-native';
import { DrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";

class MyHomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawer: () => ({
      label: 'Home'
    }),
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
        title="Open drawer"
      />
    );
  }
}

class MyNotificationsScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawer: () => ({
      label: 'Notifications'
    }),
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
        title="Go back home"
      />
    );
  }
}

const MyApp = DrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: MyHomeScreen,
  },
  Notifications: {
    screen: MyNotificationsScreen,
  },
});


export default MyApp;
```